# source.setEngine is not a function

Tags: web3js, web3-providers

So everything worked fine in truffle 4.1.14, but when I upgraded to 5.0.0 I got this error:

```
TypeError: source.setEngine is not a function
  at Web3ProviderEngine.addProvider (node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:71:10
```

I'm using this require:

```
const ProviderEngine = require('web3-provider-engine')
```

And this is the code that is cusing the error:

```
var engine = new ProviderEngine()

 engine.addProvider(web3.currentProvider)
```

Is it a bug with web3 provider engine? 
Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Truffle 5 has upgraded web3 version from 0 to 1.

Comment: But its web3-provider-engine thats failing not web3?